# InputStream of mp3 file to MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media

My humble mp3 file:
[image]

And the code to play the mp3 file:
(I get a file doesnt exist error )

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) getAssets().open("skase.mp3");
    mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing part of the path. The path you are providing assumes that the mp3 is directly in the assets folder which its not. It's insude the tracks folder in the assets folder.

Here's what you need:

`FileInputStream inputStream = (FileInputStream) getAssets().open("tracks/skase.mp3");`

Comment: @Zarkopafilis Then why accept this answer if it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You must open full path to file, example: tracks/skase.mp3

```
 FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) getAssets().open("tracks/skase.mp3");
```